# KIVY: How can I get the correct class?

Tags: python, class, kivy

I used to do

```
MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids[some_id].focus = True
```

and it worked fine. Now I added a screen manager and this gives me the error: `KeyError: 'some_id'`

I tried

```
MainLayout().ids[some_id].focus = True
```

as the screen's class is MainLayout and it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't do anything... The other screen is named LoadingScreen if that matters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you have a screen manager try this:

```
ScreenManager:
        id: screenmanager
        SomeScreen:
           name: 'somescreen'
           id: somescreen

MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids['somescreen'].ids['some_id'].focus = True
```

So what it does it that it goes to that class name  which is defined in the screen manger and gets the specified id from that class. Note that you have to give the name as defined in the your screenmanager